# How do I make everything centered when page is zoomed out?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I've just made the switch from Bootstrap to [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) and having some problems with the grid system.

Using Bootstrap I could set a `max-width` of 1600px so that the content wouldn't disappear to the sides when someone zooms out to ridiculous levels (no one really would and still expect the page to work but I still want to cover my bases). With Semantic, there are two outcomes:

1) With a `max-width` the entire page is left-aligned and cut off at 1600px.

2) Without a `max-width` things are are spaced out waaay too much (always connected to the edges), and the header content disappears to the left.

If you visit [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/)'s home page and zoom out, you can see that the page is centered along with the header *content* (not the header background), and I suppose that they use their own framework for their page so it has to be possible somehow.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible or not due to my lack of experience with semantic-UI (I've never used it) but the Semantic UI website uses `media` queries.. This may be to make the website look more suited to mobile phones and other small devices but it may be because Semantic simply doesn't have an *option*

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0 auto;`. Example:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Using this method all content, including backgrounds and headers, will be segmented into a 1600px wide box. It's not a terrible solution, but it's not what I see happening on a lot of webpages out there.

Comment: I think the idea is to only apply this to the *actual content*; as in, not the elements that contain the backgrounds and headers.

Comment: Yes, you need to use `container` class to your elements that need fixed size. So the background is in div with full size, and inside that place element with `container` class. Btw Semantic UI site is using so many media query to handle left and right padding.